# SOQL query option

Tags: apex, soql

I need to use the Order  by in the below query but still not able to get can anyone help me out

```
List<CAF__c> CF = new List<CAF__c>();
CF = [SELECT TYP_R__c FROM CAF__c  
                   WHERE cust__c = :AccrecId
                   AND TYP_R__c IN('C-D-F','C-D-D') Order by CreatedDate ASC NULLS LAST WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 250];

System.debug('End of Query');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Order by` goes after `with security_enforced`.

P.S. You don't need to initialize a variable twice. You can drop the `new List<CAF__c>`:

```
List<CAF__c> CF = [
    SELECT TYP_R__c 
    FROM CAF__c  
    WHERE cust__c = :AccrecId
    AND TYP_R__c IN ('C-D-F','C-D-D') 
    WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED 
    ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC NULLS LAST 
    LIMIT 250];

System.debug('End of Query');
```

Comment: Here is the Complete Code

Comment: @simran I realized the order was wrong, actually. See revision.